# Unable to uninstall google chrome due to duplicating processes?

Tags: google-chrome, uninstall, task-manager

Google chrome has been very laggy, internet explorer is not, tried to uninstall it but says its opened, opened task manager end the processes, keeps duplicating.

used avast anti virus, cc cleaner, defragmentation. repeatedly. remained the same, deleted all extension. cleared all history, cookies cache and things from beginning of time. does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to restart your computer? This should fix it, because any running process will be sent the terminate signal, and it has no other choice than obeying. I guess you're on a windows machine, so if after a normal restart still Google Chrome is stated open, then you cloud try restarting into the safe boot mode. This will prevent additional applications to be loaded besides the really neccessary system service. Google Chrome should really stay closed then (of course, make sure to not open it manually).

To do so:

1. Shut down your computer if it's running (the normal way, from the start menu)
2. When it's shut down, spot the F8-Key on your keyboard
3. Power your machine on using its power bower button, and
4. Immediately start pressing the F8-Key **before** the windows boot animation appears (so you're best to do so right after your BIOS / EFI message if you have one)
5. A menu will appear to ask you how to boot windows, choose "safe boot" (none of the additional features, just the plain "safe boot")
6. Windows will load (don't be scared of the missing boot animation)
7. When it's booted, log in to your account (your screen resolution might not be detected, so don't be scared of less space on your screen and huge pixels)
8. Try uninstalling Google Chrome the normal way (using Windows' built-in Control Center)
9. Restart your computer (the normal way, from the start menu), and it should start up normally
10. You should be rid of Google Chrome now

Avast Antivirus, Defragmentation or even CC Cleaner are a nice try, but usually won't change anything.